# Cooling a Room with No Windows

Tags: hvac

I am trying to determine the most effective way to cool my bedroom which runs about *5 degrees warmer* than the rest of the living space:

[image]

Questions:

1. What is the most effective way to bring the bedroom temperature more inline with the rest of the living space utilizing only the devices shown in the illustration above (central A/C would be awesome but isn't going to happen)?
2. Should the Honeywell fan blow cool air into the bedroom or blow air out of it? If out, should the fan be positioned on the floor or elevated?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In my opinion what you're asking is futile.  You're not going to get adequate cooling from a relatively small 10,000 BTU unit over such a large area.

Comment: @jwh20 Please recommend the proper BTU.

Comment: Remember that heat rises, cold sinks. If you're trying to blow cold into the room, the fan should be at the floor. If you're trying to blow hot out of the room, the fan should be at the ceiling (or top of the door opening). You could even do both. That said, 500 Sq Ft is probably going to be more than your 10,000 BTU AC can handle, but the fans would be better than nothing if you can't replace the window unit. Maybe try turning the fans from `Med` to `High`. It will be noisier, but if it's cooler, that's the trade-off you'll have to make.

Comment: The problem is not just the BTU rating.  You could install a 100K BTU unit and you'd turn the living room into a walk-in freezer but still not cool the bedroom like you want.  What's missing is DUCTWORK to carry the conditioned air to where it's needed.  How about cutting a hole in the wall of the bedroom and putting a window unit there?

Comment: Good point, @jwh20. If the wall isn't the OPs to cut into, though, that could cause _issues_ with the property owner. At a minimum, it probably means not getting a damage deposit back. :)

Comment: I'll note that they also market "ventless" air conditioners, which are essentially evaporative coolers with limited effectiveness in places where humidity is also high.  Another possibility might be a "ductless mini-split" unit.  There you locate the compressor away from the air handler connected by hoses.

Comment: a small fan blowing out from the top of the bedroom doorway would help a lot; it's much easier to remove the hot air than push in cold air.

Comment: @dandavis Any product recommendations? Is this too small to be effective?: [link](https://www.amazon.com/Achla-Designs-Room-Minuteman-Doorway/dp/B001FXVJ1U)

Comment: that would help. it might be a little loud at that diameter/cfm. An adjustable speed one would be ideal to dial in perf/noise. Blowing out helps because it directly removes the hottest air, naturally sucking in cooler air below it. Also, I just noticed your ceiling fan. Can you reverse it to blow onto the ceiling? Most have a small black switch somewhere on the hub for that. You'll lose the breeze, BUT it will shove hot air from the ceiling "umbrella" down to where the air is circulating, removing a large mass hot air that mixes with any cold air you can bring in. worth trying for a day or so.